# Adding and Removing ComboBoxes Programmatically to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

While I have no difficulty to add programmatically I can not remove the combo boxes. In this code, I tried to assign name but I couldn't used that name in any manner when I try to delete.

When I try to delete, I also tried to use cell numbers but it didn't work. I would appreciate help for this problem which kept me for hours now :(

```
Set curCombo = Worksheets("Nodes").Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, Left:=Cells(i, 1).Left, Top:=Cells(i, 1).Top, Width:=100, Height:=Rows(2).RowHeight)

method_name = "Set_Node_Name"


With curCombo
        .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 44
        .ControlFormat.ListFillRange = "Node_Type_Names!$A$1:$A$44"
        .ControlFormat.LinkedCell = "B" & i
        .OnAction = method_name
        '.Name = "myCombo" & i

End With
```

Comment: "in this code I couldn't assign names to the combo and this effects my deletion/removal problem" but you didn't state why or what error.

Comment: If you want to remove all of the comboxes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24252482/4717755) shows you a quick way to do it. Adding a name to the combobox is possible, but can be a bit [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15569361/4717755).

Comment: @sorceri you are right. I couldn'r repeat the error so I will edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterT thanks. I want to remove only from some specific cells.

Comment: What have you tried to delete the comboboxes? If you want to delete by name you should simply be able to use the `Shapes` collection of the worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Intersect` you can determine if the combobox is in a range you want to delete from.

I'm using column B here.

```
Sub removeCombos()
    Dim combo As DropDown
    Dim irng As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each combo In .DropDowns
            Set irng = Application.Intersect(combo.TopLeftCell, .Range("B:B"))
            If Not irng Is Nothing Then
                combo.Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```